# How to setup multi-choice route in express app?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have defined a route in my express app as such :

```
app.get('/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:fromdate/:todate',(req,res,next) =>{...})
```

But now I would want to add extra parameters if the `:space` parameter is equal to a specific value. For example, if `:space` is `blah` then the route should transform into

```
app.get('/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:param3/:fromdate/:todate',(req,res,next) =>{...})
```

Is that possible without hard-coding the `blah` keyword and putting the hard-coded path before the generic one ?

Answer (score 0):

The addition of extra parameter renders it as a new distinct route, so I think performing a redirect to that new route whenever you encounter `:space = blah` should satisfy your requirement.

[res.redirect()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

Added code as per OP request

```
app.get('/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:fromdate/:todate', (req, res, next) => {
  let param3 = 'sample';
  if (req.params.space === 'blaah') {
    res.redirect(`/ts/${req.params.space}/${req.params.mode}/${req.params.param1}/${req.params.param2}/${param3}/${req.params.fromdate}/${req.params.todate}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you use it precisely in my case please ? I'm not familiar with it yet.

Comment: @Chapo I hope this was what you were looking for. I have added code as well.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know `param3` in advance though. Any way to get it from the route ?

Comment: But param3 is not present in the first route also

Comment: Yes that's the whole point :) I would want the app to know to switch to a route that includes param3 if the space param is a certain value

Comment: Ohk but where would param3's value come from? It certainly has to be defined somewhere. How about as a query Param?

Comment: sounds like what I want to do is not possible. I'll have to hardcode the `:space` params to force express to use the route I want.

Comment: I am not totally sure what your requirement is, but the thing is param3 value should come from somewhere, if you can tell me where you think it would come from, maybe I can help you with this then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191946/discussion-between-chapo-and-kiran-mathew-mohan).

Answer (score 0):

Split your handler functions to isolate functions.

```
app.get('/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:fromdate/:todate', handler1)

app.get('/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:param3/:fromdate/:todate', handler2)
```

and trick to `handler1` special case:

```
const handler1 = (req,res,next) => {
  if (req.params.space === "blah") {
    // use hanler for `/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:param3/:fromdate/:todate` route
    // force set param3 value,
    req.params['param3'] = "maybe_a_default_value";
    return handler2(req,res,next);
  }
  // handler for `/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:fromdate/:todate` route
}

const handler2 = (req,res,next) => {
  // handler for `/ts/:space/:mode/:param1/:param2/:param3/:fromdate/:todate`
  // now, req.params.space === "blah" and req.params.param3 === "maybe_a_default_value" 
}
```

Comment: Thks for your answer. My handler is the same. Within the handler I check `space` and then do different things assuming the rest of the parameters exist (so `param3` in the case of space=blah). Would your solution pickup `req.params.param3` within my handler or would my intended `param3` just be `fromdate` ?

Comment: ohh, just set `param3` value in your `handler1`, I updated my answer.

Comment: ok thanks. Don't think it works for my use case then because I don't know `param3` beforehand. I need `handler2` to pick it up from the path. Is that possible ?

Comment: You can pick `param3` in `handler2` like another path params (`req.params` just is an object). ....In `handler1` you can set `param3` for next handler, everything can be  set to `param3`, `req.params['param3'] = req.params['fromdate']` - This is what you want?

Comment: If you need to pick it up from during path, you can either have it as 2 different APIs and call the same handler for the 2 APIs or define that extra Param as a query parameter for the API. If it's the same handler there's no point in having 2 distinct APIs unless one is authenticated and other is not